# Voting issue rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ranking

I'm using Acts as Votable and rails 4

I have three models: Post, User, and Comment.

I want users to be able to vote on comments.

Comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  acts_as_votable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  acts_as_voter
end
```

Now, however, whenever I create a new comment, it's already voted up by the User? If I print out `<%= current_user.find_voted_items %>` I get a new one every time I add a comment, without voting on them?

My comments_controller create action looks like:

```
def create
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
@comment.post_id = @post.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: I'm not sure I could spot anything that would cause that behavior from what you've shown us here.  What is `find_voted_items` actually returning?  What does `@user.get_voted Comment` show you as well?

Comment: It returns a Rails association eg: `[#<Comment id: 3, ` and so on. The other command returns: `#<Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb9cd45d060> true`

Comment: Okay, does the same thing come up when you create a new comment?  Again; not seeing anything immediately apparent that would cause the comment to be upvoted upon its persistence (then again, you haven't shown us the controller that *creates* any of these comments).

Comment: @Makoto, yes when I create a new comment it is added on to the association. I'll post the controller, though it's pretty standard.